# Счетчик просмотров

Tags: счетчики, база-данных, видео

Добрый день.

Хочу сделать счетчик количества просмотров видео.

Вот код:

```
<div class="placehold">
<iframe width="100%" height="100%" frameborder="0" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/videoid"></iframe>
<div id="play_button" onclick="location.href = '?y=test';"></div>
</div>
```

При нажатии на `play_button` php скриптом открывается iframe.

`placehold` - заглушка видео.

`play_button` - кнопка воспроизвести.

`?y=test` - хеш видео в бд, по которому получаем ссылку на видео.

Хочеться, чтобы при нахождении на странице `example.com/?y=test` через 5 минут в базу данных добавлялась еденица, если раньше, то просмотр не считается.
Думаю в сторону JS, но в нем не разбираюсь. Помогите, кто знает, пожалуйста.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

На JS можно запустить таймер:

```
timer = setInterval(saveCounter, 300000);
```

В функции saveCounter делается ajax-запрос к php-файлу на сервере, который будет сохранять счетчик. Например:

```
function saveCounter()
{
    $.ajax({
        url: "/class/counter.php?action=addConter",
        success:
            function(data) {
                console.log("Success!");
            },
        error:
            function() {
                console.log("ERROR!")
            },
        cache: false
    })
}
```

Comment: Спасибо) 

Решил немного иначе:
setTimeout( pushget, 300000); - через 5 минут срабатывает функция

Сама функция:
<script type="text/javascript">
function pushget() {
 var x = new XMLHttpRequest();
 x.open("GET", "?y=1&s", true);
 x.send(null);
}
</script>

php считает по гет запросу - s, запрос - y, служит для передачи хеша видео в бд(для поиска строки)

Может быть можно решить проще и красивее но с js знаком 1 день)

Comment: Я хотел и такой вариант предложить. Но мне проще было часть своего кода скопировать :)